# Text beyond the column

Tags: multicolumn

The text goes out of the column, how can I fix this?  I need it `flalign`, we better not take it out.
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=19.0cm,paperheight=27.5cm,margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol,enumitem}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1.7pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.2cm}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{2}

\begin{enumerate}[left=0pt,label=\bfseries\arabic*.,ref=\arabic*]
\item No problem here. Text does not exceed the column.
\begin{flalign*}
    &x^2+y^2 \text{But here the text exceeds the column. How can I solve the problem here?}& 
\end{flalign*}
\end{enumerate}

\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\text` is an `\mbox` so always one line. You could remove `falign` and `\text` in this example, or if it has to be in math use `\parbox{3cm}{but here ...}` instead of `\text`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by placing non-math material in a displayed equation? (Hint: I would *not* expect this to go well...) Please  tell us about your use case.

Comment: I use it for equation but I need to write it in prose. so i use both at the same time @Mico

Comment: I don't quite understand, Can you recompile the code? @DavidCarlisle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\text` is essentially `\mbox` so does not allow linebreaking. It's normally best to avoid placing paragraph level texts inside math, but if you must, you can use `\parbox`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=19.0cm,paperheight=27.5cm,margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol,enumitem}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1.7pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.2cm}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{2}

\begin{enumerate}[left=0pt,label=\bfseries\arabic*.,ref=\arabic*]
\item No problem here. Text does not exceed the column.
\begin{flalign*}
    &x^2+y^2 \quad \parbox[t]{4cm}{But here the text exceeds the column. How can I solve the problem here?}& 
\end{flalign*}
\end{enumerate}

\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

`flalign*` is certainly being mis-used in this small example, but perhaps your real document has some alignment where it makes sense.

Comment: Yes that's, but I want to include x^2+y^2 as well @David Carlisle

Comment: ```&\parbox[t]{7.cm}{$x^2+y^2$ But here the text exceeds the column. How can I solve the problem here?}&``` is worked but I got a red alert @David Carlisle

Comment: @cufcuf  the width of the parbox is no different to having a+yyyy+zzzz+1111+2222+3333+4444 in the math part of `flalign` that will also over-print. There is no automatic line breaking in a math display, you need to use a display that fits. So you solve the problem by changing 7cm to 4cm or by using a more appropriate environment eg John's tabularx suggestion

Comment: But I am completely confused by your suggestion to put the math _inside_ the parbox, what is the point of that????  why are you using `flalign` here at all if you are not aligning any math?????? @cufcuf

Answer (score 2):

This achieves the same effect using tabularx.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=19.0cm,paperheight=27.5cm,margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol,enumitem}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1.7pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.2cm}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{2}

\begin{enumerate}[left=0pt,label=\bfseries\arabic*.,ref=\arabic*]
\item No problem here. Text does not exceed the column.

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}cX@{}}
 $x^2+y^2$ &
But here the text exceeds the column. How can I solve the problem here?
\end{tabularx}
\end{enumerate}

\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```